# ORA-00911: invalid character in C#, escape character

Tags: c#, oracle

I have the next query in a C# application and get the error of the title

```
select to_char(bepr450030, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), count(1)
from cag.bepr09tb01, cag.bepr10tb01, cag.bepr45tb01, cag.bepr13tb01, cag.bepr08tb01
where bepr090030 = 2 and bepr090010 = bepr100040 and bepr450020 = bepr100010 and                bepr450040 = bepr130010 and bepr130025 = bepr080010 and
bepr450030 > ({ts '2014-03-01 00:00:00'}) 
and bepr450260 = 'N' and bepr090010 < > 10000381 and bepr090010< > 692863 and 
bepr450040 = 215 group by bepr450040, to_char(bepr450030, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
order by bepr450040, to_char(bepr450030, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

I've delimited the error and that happens in the next line:

```
 bepr450030 > ({ts '2014-03-01 00:00:00'})
```

I think is because of the  {} characters but I'm mot sure and I've been looking for a solution and escaping the characters but I haven`t found it. Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the type of `bepr450030` column? What is `ts`? Why do you need to use `{ }` in your case? This query work in your database engine? What a terrible column name by the way..

Comment: Hi, yes, it works in the database engine. **bepr450030** is a timestamp. I'm not sure what ts and {} is used for, I've been working in Sql Server and DB2 for several years but I'm a novice in Oracle, the query was simply given to me. I think that **ts** is an Oracle function to cast from char to timestamp.

Comment: Are you using ODBC? This is syntax used in ODBC connections. 'ts' means 'timestamp' (date + time)

Comment: You can find a description here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710282(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, I'm using ODBC. The query is correct, it works in the database engine, the problem is when I  try to run it from the application I'm developing in C#. I have other Oracle queries but this one is the only that fails.